# How to use SCIP to solve SAT problems?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, scip, sat

I am trying to use SCIP to solve a SAT problem. My company uses a Linux command line by Mobaxterm.
I have the SCIPoptsuite 6.0.2 installed.
I'm unable to find any information online on how to call SCIP to solve SAT problems, both in English and Chinese. I have many cnf files that I would like to call SCIP to solve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HngYZ.png)

Would anybody be able to guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the interactive shell of SCIP, you can just read a problem and solve it.

So, start your SCIP binary (if its globally installed, just executing `scip` should be sufficient; otherwise, call the binary from the location where you installed it).

Then, in the interactive shell, read the problem, e.g., `read 115_3448s.cnf` and solve it: `optimize`. Afterward, you can print via `display solution`. See https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/SHELL.php for a short tutorial on the interactive shell.

Note that SCIP is a CIP solver and normally uses an LP relaxation for bounding. This can be disabled if you want to solve SAT instances (`set emphasis cpsolver`), but there is still significant overhead compared to a dedicated SAT solver. Thus, if you only want to solve pure SAT instances, you might want to try out a dedicated SAT solver. If you consider adding some other general linear constraints later on, however, SCIP should be a good option.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerald, I finally got it to work!